# Roots of this cubic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my example I got 1,2,3 as roots. However the actual roots are 1,1,2. Where is my mistake here? And what method should I follow?  Badly need to get this fundamental... Thank u [image: factorization]

Comment: How does $\lambda[\lambda^2-4\lambda+5]=2$ imply that $\lambda=2$ or $\lambda^2-4\lambda+5=2$ as you have written? Also, $\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+5\lambda-2=0\implies \lambda(\lambda^2-4\lambda+4)+(\lambda-2)=0\implies \lambda(\lambda-2)^2+(\lambda-2)=0$. Can you handle it from here?

Comment: You basically have $AB=2$ in the third line, which you interpreted as meaning either $A=2$ or $B=2$. This is not true (for example, if $A$ were $\frac12$ and $B$ were $4$). _However_, if you get something of the form $AB=0$, you could conclude either $A=0$ or $B=0$, since the product of nonzero numbers is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, in the cubic equation:$\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+5\lambda-2=0$,  the sum of coefficients of even power terms is equal to the sum of coefficients of odd power terms hence $\lambda=1$  is a root of the cubic equation hence $(\lambda-1)$ is a factor of $(\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+5\lambda-2)$ hence, using division one should have 
$$\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+5\lambda-2=(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2-3\lambda+2)$$ 
Further factorizing $\lambda^2-3\lambda+2$, one should get,
$$\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+5\lambda-2=(\lambda-1)(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$$
hence, the cubic equation is $$(\lambda-1)(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)=0$$